# TypeError: Merging undefined is not supported

Tags: vue.js, node-modules, quasar-framework, quasar, webpack-merge

I got this error when running `$ quasar dev` on my Vue project

```
~/project/node_modules/webpack-merge/dist/index.js:63
            throw new TypeError("Merging undefined is not supported");
                  ^

[  TypeError: Merging undefined is not supported

  - index.js:63 mergeWithOptions
    [project]/[webpack-merge]/dist/index.js:63:19

  - index.js:52 merge
    [project]/[webpack-merge]/dist/index.js:52:35

  - quasar-conf-file.js:392 QuasarConfFile.compile
    [project]/[@quasar]/app/lib/quasar-conf-file.js:392:29

  - task_queues:96 processTicksAndRejections
    node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5

  - quasar-dev:237 async goLive
    [project]/[@quasar]/app/bin/quasar-dev:237:3

]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue is [the wrong quasar version](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/9846#issuecomment-869749596).

My dependencies are

```
"dependencies": {
  "quasar": "^1.0.0",
  ...
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@quasar/app": "^2.0.0",
```

But when I ran `npm install`, it asked me to ran `npm audit fix --force` and it would change the `@quasar/app` version. You would need to reset the package.json and run `npm install` again to fix it.

```
14 vulnerabilities (7 moderate, 7 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```